# How to pause and unpause a video

Tags: html, css, video

I have this code inside

and I have the **.css the class myvideo** (It doesn't need this code ),it is the design.
What I want to know is ,how can I do pause and unpause this video.I try  to stop my video and I didn't manage it.If you could help me with it I will be greatful.Thanks

```
<div class="myvideo" style="left: 6px; top: 0px">
<video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
<source src="exr.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: You can put controls as an attribute in the video element. Or if you want to do it programmatically in Javascript it’s videoelement.play() and videoelement.pause().

Comment: @A.Haworth if you can answer so I tick it .I would be greatful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have control over a video element you must use JavaScript to control it. Here's a great example of how to control a video object from JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp

You may need to add another HTML element to control your video. This element must listen to a click event. After that, you will be able to do what you want with the video.

```
const videoEl = document.getElementById("video-bg-elem");

// Will play the video
videoEl.play();

// Will pause the video
videoEl.pause();
```